# Vieux garcon game - Problem with execution

Tags: python

how would I solve this problem? The program is supposed to remove all pairs from your hand at the beginning but it is not working. This is what it outputs at the moment:

```
Hello. I am Robot and I distribute the cards.
Your hand is:
2♠ 5♡ Q♠ Q♡ 4♡ J♢ 2♣ J♠ K♢ 8♢ 10♠ A♣ 5♣ 3♣ 6♣ 4♢ 7♣ 9♢ 2♢ J♡ A♢ 8♠ 10♣ 6♢ 10♡ 
Don't worry, I cannot see your cards or their order.
Now discard all pairs in your hand. I will do it too.
Press Enter to continue. 
************************************************************
Your turn.
Your hand is: 
9♢ J♡ 3♣ K♢ 10♠ 2♢ 10♣ 10♡ 7♣
```

There is not supposed to be two 10s in your hand. This is the code:

```
# vieux garcon card game.
import random

def wait_for_player():
  try:
    input("Press Enter to continue. ")
  except SyntaxError:
    pass

def prepare_pack():
  pack = []
  colors = ['♠', '♡', '♢', '♣']
  value = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
  for val in value:
    for color in colors:
      pack.append(val + color)
  pack.remove('J♣') 
  return pack


def shuffle_pack(p):
  random.shuffle(p)


def give_cards(p):

  giver = []
  other = []

  loop = 0
  for i in p:
    if (loop % 2) == 0:
      giver.append(i)
    else:
      other.append(i)
    loop += 1

  return (giver, other)


def remove_pairs(l):

  colors = ['♠', '♡', '♢', '♣']
  result = []

  for crt in l:
    if crt[1] + crt[0] == '10':
      nbr = '10'
    else:
      nbr = crt[0]
    for i in colors:
      find = False
      if nbr + i in result:
        find = True
        result.remove(nbr + i)
        break
    if find == False:
      result.append(crt)

  random.shuffle(result)
  return result


def show_cards(p):

  for i in p:
    print(i, end = " ")
  print()


def enter_valid_position(n):

  enter = int(input('Please enter a number from 1 to'+ str(n) +": ")) - 1
  while enter not in range(0, n):
    enter = int(input('Invalid position. Please enter a number from 1 to ' + str(n) +": ")) - 1
  return enter

def play():

  p = prepare_pack()
  shuffle_pack(p)
  tmp = give_cards(p)
  giver = tmp[0]
  human = tmp[1]

  print("Hello. I am Robot and I distribute the cards.")
  print("Your hand is:")
  show_cards(human)
  print("Don't worry, I cannot see your cards or their order.")
  print(
    "Now discard all pairs in your hand. I will do it too."
  )
  wait_for_player()

  giver = remove_pairs(giver)
  human = remove_pairs(human)

  #Instance = 1, human's turn, instance = 2, robot's turn
  instance = 1
  while instance in range(1,2): 
        
    if instance == 1:
      print('*' * 60)

      print('Your turn.')
      print('Your hand is: ')
      show_cards(human)

      print("I have ", len(giver), "cards. If 1 is the position of my first card and ")
      print(len(giver), "is the position of my last card, which card do you want?")
      entry = enter_valid_position(len(giver))
      print("You asked for my card number ", entry+1, ".")
      print("There it is. It is a ", giver[entry])
      print("With ", giver[entry]," added, your hand is:")
      human.append(giver[entry])
      giver.remove(giver[entry])
      show_cards(human)
      human=remove_pairs(human)

      if len(human) == 0:
        print("I finished all the cards.")
        win = True
        break

      print("After discarding all pairs and shuffling the cards, your hand is:")
      show_cards(human)
      wait_for_player()
            
      instance = 2
      pass

    if instance == 2:
      print('*' * 60)

      print('My turn.')
      take_card = random.randint(0, len(human) - 1)
      giver.append(human[take_card])
      human.remove(human[take_card])
      print("I took your card number ", take_card+1,".")
      giver=remove_pairs(giver)

      if len(giver)==0:
        print("I finished all the cards.")
        win = False
        break

      wait_for_player()
      instance = 1
      pass

  if win == True:
    print("Congratulations! You, Human, have won.")
  else:
    print("You lost! Me, Robot, have won.")

# main
play()
```

What should I do? My program does remove pairs later on in the game, but not at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error.

```
 for crt in l:
    if crt[1] + crt[0] == '10':
      nbr = '10'
```

I flipped the positions of the 1 and 0. it was checking for 01 and not 10. It was supposed to be:

```
 for crt in l:
    if crt[0] + crt[1] == '10':
      nbr = '10'
```

Sorry for the inconvience.